# Issue with Mootools morph - div overlaying an image

Tags: html, css, mootools

Wonder if anyone could shed some light on this

http://jsfiddle.net/orbitalmedia/ZrxBb/7/

Basically I'm trying to create a blind effect over an image. addClass or toggleClass is able to apply the style but I'm trying to morph the overlay so it animates over the image.

Ta

Edit..

This works but I'm trying to accomplish the same thing using morph and a css class

$('span_2_0').tween('width', 150);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do `.morph(".classname")`, it will only take the properties it CAN morph and apply them, i.e. color, size etc. not z-index or position.

in any case, you need the . before the classname and then set the base css properties beforehand:

```
$('span_2_0').morph('.overlay');
```

do not use color names. use hex values that can be morphed.

```
#span_2_0 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;  
    background-color: #fff;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    width:75px;
    height:150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrxBb/12/